# Why do we need to specify a format driver with fiona?

Tags: python, shapefile, fiona

What are format drivers for?

For example why is this necessary:

```
    with fiona.open(save_file, "w", driver="ESRI Shapefile", schema=schema) as c:
```

Shouldn't it just be able to figure out the format driver given that the save_file ends in `shp`?

Comment: Do you get an error when you omit the driver argument?

Comment: @Shawn I get a `fiona.errors.DriverError: no driver` exception. Specifying a driver on write is compulsory, I guess its a design choice to save the author having to work out a filename-to-driver mapping.

Comment: It is possible to give any file any extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been [implemented](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/pull/948) and is coming in [version 1.9](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/releases/tag/1.9a1) (not yet released)